# targeting class attributes to to add :after

Tags: css

I have 4 links and have added "|" imbetween each link.

```
.linkblock li a:after {content:" |"; white-space: pre;}
```

I have used to remove "|" from the first child which works:

```
.linkblock li a:first-child:after {content:" "; white-space: pre;}
```

for the last child i have tried a lot but last child doesnt work. The last one used:

```
.linkblock li a:nth-child(4):after  {content:" "; white-space: pre;}
```

but fails to do anything.

Is the a way to change it?

```css
.linkblock li a:after {content: " |"; white-space: pre}
.linkblock li a:first-child:after {content: ""; white-space: pre}
.linkblock li a:nth-child(4):after {content: ""; white-space: pre}
```

```html
<div class="linkblock float-left f15 ml-2">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span><a class="linkblockf"  href="#investment-platform">Client Platform</a></li>
    <li><span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span><a class="linkblockf" href="#golden-visa">Country Programmes</a></li>
    <li><span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span><a class="linkblockf" href="#ahimsa-investments">Ahimsa Investments</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your second and third examples are identical. You need to use `:last-child` in the last one.

Comment: updated, last and nth doesnt work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier way with less and cleaner code is to target `li`'s that follow other `li`'s (with the *adjacent sibling combinator* or `+`) so that the first one is automatically excluded, and by using the `:before` pseudo-element instead, you don't even have to target the last one to "hide" the `content`:

```css
.linkblock li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.linkblock li + li:before {
  content: "|";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkblock float-left f15 ml-2">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span>
      <a class="linkblockf" href="#investment-platform">Client Platform</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span>
      <a class="linkblockf" href="#golden-visa">Country Programmes</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span>
      <a class="linkblockf" href="#ahimsa-investments">Ahimsa Investments</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats really clean thank you will play with that some  more.

Answer (score 0):

Last child and first child belong to li elements. And you don't need to target the first element:

```css
.linkblock li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.linkblock li a:after {
  content:" |";
  white-space: pre;
}
.linkblock li:last-child a:after {
  content:" "; 
}
```

```html
<div class="linkblock float-left f15 ml-2">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span><a class="linkblockf"  href="#investment-platform">Client Platform</a></li>
        <li><span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span><a class="linkblockf" href="#golden-visa">Country Programmes</a></li>
        <li><span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span><a class="linkblockf" href="#ahimsa-investments">Ahimsa Investments</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok amazing makes sense. structured approach to targeting elements. Thank you